# Autofac - how to register a type used as a constructor parameter that requires the resolving (constructor) type as a generic parameter

Tags: autofac

I have a logger type ILogger.

For any type T that requires an ILogger in its constructor, the instance of ILogger is created using a factory method, Logger.For(), that uses the type T as a generic parameter. For example:

```
class Foo
{
    private ILogger logger;
    public Foo(Ilogger logger) 
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo(Logger.For<Foo>());
}
```

Is there a way that I can register the logger factory in Autofac such that any Autofac registered type T that has an ILogger parameter in its constructor is automatically given an instance from Logger.For()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [example of something like this in the Autofac docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html) that uses log4net. Instead of `Logger.For<T>()` it's `LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(T))` but it holds.

First step will be to figure out given a `Type` object how to create a generic method call. You can do that [with `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Something like...

```
private static object GetLogger(Type forType)
{
  // Get the LogManager.For<T>() method.
  var openMethod = typeof(LogManager).GetMethod("For", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
  // Actually put the T in For<T>().
  var closedMethod = openMethod.MakeGenericMethod(forType);
  // Invoke the static method.
  return closedMethod.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Now you can use the example almost out of the box.

```
public class LoggingModule : Autofac.Module
{
  private static void InjectLoggerProperties(object instance)
  {
    var instanceType = instance.GetType();

    // Get all the injectable properties to set.
    // If you wanted to ensure the properties were only UNSET properties,
    // here's where you'd do it. Also, update the typeof() call/filter thing
    // here as needed.
    var properties = instanceType
      .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
      .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(ILog) && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0);

    // Set the properties located.
    foreach (var propToSet in properties)
    {
      propToSet.SetValue(instance, LogManager.GetLogger(instanceType), null);
    }
  }

  private static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
  {
    e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(
      new[]
      {
        // Again, update the check here to ensure you're only filling in the
        // right parameters.
        new ResolvedParameter(
            (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILog),
            // Here's the call to that generic method.
            (p, i) => GetLogger(p.Member.DeclaringType)
        ),
      });
  }

  protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
  {
    // Handle constructor parameters.
    registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;

    // Handle properties.
    registration.Activated += (sender, e) => InjectLoggerProperties(e.Instance);
  }

  private static object GetLogger(Type forType)
  {
    // Get the LogManager.For<T>() method.
    var openMethod = typeof(LogManager).GetMethod("For", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    // Actually put the T in For<T>().
    var closedMethod = openMethod.MakeGenericMethod(forType);
    // Invoke the static method.
    return closedMethod.Invoke(null, null);
  }
}
```

Caveat: I haven't actually compiled this. I'm kinda going off the top of my head pretty quick. But this should do it.